# Incorrect time with FullName Timezone

Tags: java, datetime, timezone

I am trying to convert time from timezone to another using fullname timezone. Below is the java api i have used.

```
    TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Africa/Algiers"));
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    String dateInString = "09:44:00";
    TimeZone tzGMT01 = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Africa/Algiers");
    formatter.setTimeZone(tzGMT01);

    Date dateInAmerica = formatter.parse(dateInString);
    String fromInput = formatter.format(dateInAmerica);
    TimeZone tzGMT03 = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Bahrain");
    formatter.setTimeZone(tzGMT03); 

    String toInput = formatter.format(dateInAmerica);
    Time ts = java.sql.Time.valueOf(toInput);
```

The expected output for time value of `09:44:00` converted to "Asia/Bahrain" time is `11:44:00`. However the output is `13:44:00`.

Can someone please guide what is wrong in the above statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that a Java `Date` is a full date value, not just a time value. When you don't give year/month/day values, they default to **1970/01/01**.

The world was different back in 1970. [Algiers](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/algeria/algiers) was using UTC+0 timezone, and [Bahrain](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/bahrain/manama) was using UTC+4, which is unlike today, where Algiers is using UTC+1 timezone, and Bahrain is using UTC+3.

Ignoring date will also cause issues for timezones that has Daylight Savings Time.

As you can see, **date matters**.

Here is code to show it:

```
TimeZone tzAlgiers = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Africa/Algiers");
TimeZone tzBahrain = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Bahrain");

SimpleDateFormat fmtTimeAlgiers = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
fmtTimeAlgiers.setTimeZone(tzAlgiers);

SimpleDateFormat fmtDatetimeAlgiers = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
fmtDatetimeAlgiers.setTimeZone(tzAlgiers);

SimpleDateFormat fmtFullAlgiers = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z (Z)");
fmtFullAlgiers.setTimeZone(tzAlgiers);

SimpleDateFormat fmtFullBahrain = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z (Z)");
fmtFullBahrain.setTimeZone(tzBahrain);

Date date1970 = fmtTimeAlgiers.parse("09:44:00");
System.out.println(fmtTimeAlgiers.format(date1970) + "                          " + tzAlgiers.getID());
System.out.println(fmtFullAlgiers.format(date1970) + "   " + tzAlgiers.getID());
System.out.println(fmtFullBahrain.format(date1970) + "   " + tzBahrain.getID());
System.out.println();

Date date2016 = fmtDatetimeAlgiers.parse("2016-01-01 09:44:00");
System.out.println(fmtDatetimeAlgiers.format(date2016) + "               " + tzAlgiers.getID());
System.out.println(fmtFullAlgiers.format(date2016) + "   " + tzAlgiers.getID());
System.out.println(fmtFullBahrain.format(date2016) + "   " + tzBahrain.getID());
System.out.println();
```

*Output*

```
09:44:00                          Africa/Algiers
1970-01-01 09:44:00 CET (+0000)   Africa/Algiers
1970-01-01 13:44:00 AST (+0400)   Asia/Bahrain

2016-01-01 09:44:00               Africa/Algiers
2016-01-01 09:44:00 CET (+0100)   Africa/Algiers
2016-01-01 11:44:00 AST (+0300)   Asia/Bahrain
```

The timezone names `CET` and `AST` are actually wrong for 1970. Algiers was using `GMT`, and Bahrain was using `GST` (Gulf Standard Time).

Comment: As noted at the end of that Answer, those 3-4 letter abbreviations like `CET`, `AST`, and `GST` are a problem. They are not true time zones, are not standardized, and are not unique(!). Instead, use a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

Comment: This is correct analysis. I converted the input time to current date and appended the input time. this date time value returned correct converted values. This is very helpful. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

It should work properly, [I just did an example here](http://ideone.com/42Xqhx) using the timezone that you provided for Asia/Bahrain:

```
SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

Date currentTime = new Date();
System.out.println(f.format(currentTime.getTime()));

f.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Bahrain"));
System.out.println(f.format(currentTime.getTime()));
```

The SimpleDateForma will do the trick properly.

Here is my output:

```
> 06/18/2016 23:55:13 
> 06/19/2016 05:55:13
```